# Как вывести количество постов из рубрики в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выводить количество постов из рубрики в WordPress??

Использую для вывода рубрик

```
<?php the_category(); ?>
```

Comment: Для начала учи что делает функция https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_category